# Изменить запросом обязательное поле на необязательное

Tags: sql, access

Как изменить запросом обязательное поле на необязательное?

Использую  MS Access

Comment: покажите структуру таблицы. Это делается командой Alter.

Comment: обычная таблица из  поле,без индексов и внешних ключей.Как именно  делается? ALTER TABLE Employees ALTER COLUMN ZipCode TEXT(10) NULL ??